# Processing empty data

Tags: python, pandas

**When a column of data is empty, assign it to another column**

below my dataframe:

```
   aaa  ccc
0  4.0    3
1  NaN    2
2  NaN    3
3  1.0    2
```

i expect the dataframe:

```
   aaa  ccc
0    4    3
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    1    2
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) with `axis=1`:

```
df.bfill(1)
```

Output:

```
   aaa  ccc
0  4.0  3.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0
3  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote will be greatly appreciated :P

Answer (score 2):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`

Can take a dictionary that specifies what to fill each column with.  The `downcast='infer'` will down cast the numeric values if appropriate.

```
df.fillna({'aaa': df.ccc}, downcast='infer')

   aaa  ccc
0    4    3
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

use np.where to fill nan

```
import numpy as np
df['aaa'] = np.where(df['aaa'].isnull(),df['ccc'],df['aaa'])
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace`:

```
import numpy as np    
df['aaa'] = df['aaa'].replace(np.nan, df['ccc'])
```